# Passing javascript var in JSF commandlink

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, seam2

I'm currently stuck on a JavaScript / JSF issue.

The project I'm working on is a Seam 2 project and this is what I'm trying to do:

- On a certain page with a calendar
  view the user can select multiple
  calendar days within one month. The
  list of selected days is kept on the
  client-side using JavaScript (stored
  in a JavaScript array)
- Now when the users presses a command link button I want to call my
  component like this: `<h:commandButton
  value="View Details"
  action="#{myComponent.dateSelection}"/>`
- So far so good, however I want to be able to pass my Javascript array to this
  method as I need that data on my backend.

Does anyone knows a way to add my JS var as parameter of my component call?

Thanks for helping!

Dirk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see how you are doing things, because there is no code in your question, but a standard way of doing this is to use hidden form fields linked to an attribute of your backing bean, which you can fill using javascript.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the way to go for me!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `@WebMethod` annotation. You can by using that call this method directly from javascript and send your array as parameter in the method

Comment: I did find this also but the problem is that we cannot use remoting due to restrictions by the my client.

Comment: If you cannot use remoting, then there is no chance to pass a javascript array to a method